# Android 4.4.2 File.mkdir() and mkdirs() are creating file instead of directory

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, mkdir, mkdirs

This question is not related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953744/file-mkdir-and-mkdirs-are-creating-file-instead-of-directory). I have already seen it but it's SPECIFIC Android 4.4.2 issue as the code works fine on other versions of Android.

```
final File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MY_Downloads");

        if (!path.exists()) {
            path.mkdir(); // also tried it with path.mkdirs();
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(path)));
        }
```

I am using this code it creates a **FILE** instead of a folder on Android 4.4.2. Please help I have already read this [article](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html)

I have given following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I know how to access SD-Card and the latest changes regarding public directory but I want to create a FOLDER instead of file

Answer (score 1):

The first few generations of Android devices always used an SD Card for storage and accessing this was simply a matter of using the path provided by the SDK method

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Very soon newer devices started to appear with large internal storage partitions which are mapped as external  storage such that calls to methods like Environment.

`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String)`

now point to this internal storage rather than a physical SD Card.

Some of the very latest devices such as the Samsung Galaxy Nexus do not even have SD Card slots.

[refer this blog](http://eigo.co.uk/labs/how-to-access-sd-card-programmatically-on-android/)

i hope this help.

Comment: Dear thanks I just want to create a FOLDER not a file. I have read this and the same code is working with Android 4.3 (internal sd card the same as you are talking about)

Comment: On KitKat both methods return a path to /storage/emulated/0 which is on the internal memory. If I force to create a directory in /storage/external_SD/Android/data/<package_name>/files/Pictures then files is a file on Windows however with ES3 or Wifi File transfer it is a directory.

Comment: I tried the two slashes trick at the end with "/storage/external_SD/Android/data/<package_name>/files/dummy//" and it now creates a directory files which is visible on Windows, but dummy is still a file. Good enough for me :))
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953744/file-mkdir-and-mkdirs-are-creating-file-instead-of-directory

Comment: @Zekitez I did the 'dummy' trick too. It was the only way. 

Too bad I read you comment after hours of tests and found this trick before...You should have made an answer with that as it's an actual solution to the problem. OK, I am doing the answer for the others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on an Android 4.4.2 (and it was not a problem of slash).

For instance if I wanted to created this directory:

```
myRep/things/logs
```

It would create the first 2 directories but 'logs' would be a file, not a directory.

I resolved by adding another directory after logs like:

```
myRep/things/logs/tmp
```

Now tmp is a file, but logs is finally a directory.

Also importantly on some devices you need to do additional stuff after creating your file, this is what is working for me:

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + '/' + pathToDirectory + "/tmp");    
directory.mkdirs();
directory.setExecutable(true);
directory.setReadable(true);
directory.setWritable(true);
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[] {directory .toString()}, null, null);
```